# extracting value of variable from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one issue in selecting a value of one variable conditional on the value of another variable in a dataframe.

```
Dilutionfactor=c(1,3,9,27,80)
Log10Dilutionfactor=log10(Dilutionfactor)
Protection=c(100,81.25,40,10.52,0)
RM=as.data.frame(cbind(Dilutionfactor,Log10Dilutionfactor,Protection))
```

Now i want to know the value of Log10Dilutionfactor condition on the value of Protection is equal to either 50 (if it appear) or the value immediately just below 50.
when i used `subset(RM,Protection<= 50)`it gives three rows and when I tried `RM[grepl(RM$Protection<=50,Log10Dilutionfactor),]` it gives 0 values with warning message. I really appreciate if someone help me.

Comment: If you `cbind` before you coerce to a data.frame, you're creating a matrix (which can only hold one type) before changing to data.frame (which can hold multiple). Just use `data.frame(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 `subset`:

```
subset(RM,Protection==max(subset(RM,Protection<= 50)$Protection))$Log10Dilutionfactor
# [1] 0.954243
```

Comment: This one is easiest in solving my issue, thanking you

Comment: Yes it is not a problem with the data provided, i rechecked it and found correct. that's why i deleted the comment

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
with(RM, Log10Dilutionfactor[which(Protection == max(Protection[Protection <= 50]))])
# [1] 0.9542425
```

Answer (score 1):

or find the index value of protection that is closest to 50

```
 index = which(abs(RM$Protection-50)<=min(abs(RM$Protection-50)))
```

and then look it up in what ever column you want. e.g for Dilutionfactor

```
 RM$Dilutionfactor[index]
```